# Python 3 фильтр или сортировка словаря с условием

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть большой словарь типа `{'вася': 4, 'сон': 3, 'пол': 4}` и так далее.

Нужно получить объект, содержащий все ключи с одинаковыми значениями, при условии что заведомо не известно количество этих значений.

Желательно сортированный по возрастанию.

Можно ли в python создавать условно-именованные переменные? 
Хотелось бы, например, что-то вроде этого:

```
q = get ALL from {} where val == (foreach range(1, {}.__len__()))
```

а потом создать переменную по типу

```
create str(list({}.values.sortbyinc))
```

в которую выгрузить все ключи словаря со значением, например 1 и так для всех найденных значений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

dct = {'вася': 4, 'сон': 3, 'пол': 4}

defdct = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in dct.items():
    defdct[value].append(key)

print(defdct)

# Напечатает:
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: ['сон'], 4: ['пол', 'вася']})
# По сути это обычный словарь,
# из которого можно по числовому ключу получить список слов

# А теперь из него вот так можно получить упорядоченный словарь,
# отсортированный по возрастанию числового ключа:

sorted_dct = OrderedDict(sorted(defdct.items()))
```

Отсортировать можно и по другим признакам, если использовать аргумент key (примеры использования sorted с аргументом key легко гугляться)

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_1 = {'вася': 4, 'сон': 3, 'пол': 4}
new_object = [(x,dict_1[x]) for x in dict_1.keys() if dict_1[x] == 4]
print(new_object)
```

Результат:

```
[('вася', 4), ('пол', 4)]
```

Comment: >>>if dict_1[x] == 4]   А если значений в словаре 20 000 ? и мы не знаем заранее меьшего, большего и шаг ?

Comment: Не совсем вас понял

Comment: Скрипт анализирует текст с помощью Counter, который выдаёт словарь, ключами в котором являются слова, а значением = количество этих слов в тексте.

Comment: То что вы написали в комментарий и вопрос разные...

Comment: Ну, почему же разные? Вопрос был о возможности выборки из словаря всех ключей с одинаковым значением (1, потом 2 и т.д.) и ппочрёдном хранении таких выборок в переменной (или буфере), с условным именованием: "1", "2" и т.д